# Apply Multiple Discount Codes to a Event Registration

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

Is it possible for a registrant to enter in more than one discount code for an event? For example, if we have three tiers ($200, $400, and $600) and two add-on events ($50 and $150), can the registrant apply a code called tier1 ($100 off) and a code called addon1 ($25 off)?

Right now, if the registrant enters in the second code, it overrides the first and only the second discount code gets applied.

Basically, I'm looking for the functionality you might find on an e-commerce site where you can apply multiple coupons. I'm thinking the answer is that we'll have to build this out with a vendor; however, I'm surprised this hasn't been implemented in a prior version of the extension via a make it happen, considering the complexity of some non-profits' events.

Comment: As I understand this (and you have likely discovered in this time) this is impossible. However, this would be very useful. Can anyone shed light on how complicated it would be to actually provide a solution to this?

Comment: I'd love to see this too, would reduce discount code work for complex events